# php different hash for same image

Tags: php, hash, md5, unique

I have two identical images stored in two different servers (dropbox and my own).
however, i realize that

```
hash("md5",file_get_contents($image1))
hash("md5",file_get_contents($image2))
```

are returning different hashes for these identical images.
How can i make sure they both return the same string?

Comment: Have you actually verified the contents of `$image1` and `$image2`?

Comment: @PeeHaa Even if the images are the same, there's probably minor differences in the metadata that's avalanching down the hash.

Comment: Maybe you could try reading them with an image library, then getting the hashes of the `var_dump`s of the image variables.

Comment: @Palladium I said contents. I didn't say: do they look the same? ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa At risk of being too pedantic, metadata doesn't technically count as "content";)

Comment: @Palladium hmmmm I like it pedantic. Food for thought.

Comment: @OP Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645451/which-image-formats-contain-meta-data-and-how-can-i-clear-it-in-php. Perhaps the same method would work for you.

Comment: `file_get_contents($image1) === file_get_contents($image2)` returns `true` or `false`? Maybe try to use `md5sum` command line tool on both servers, if you are using unix-like operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using md5_file?

```
md5_file($image1);
md5_file($image2);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

Comment: Thank you! one of the thousands of pixels were off by one value.